# JAX-RS (or Quarkus) reverse routing with subresources

Tags: java, jax-rs, quarkus

I have a `ContainerRequestFilter` that gathers some metrics for each endpoint invoked in my JAX-RS/Quarkus application. This requires access to the URI patterns as specified in the `@Path` annotations on each resource ("/api/users/{userId}", not the resolved URL like "/api/users/1711")

I use the following code that works great for simple resources but fails for nested resources:

```java
class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    ResourceInfo resourceInfo

    ...

    private String getUri() {
        var uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromResource(resourceInfo.getResourceClass());
        var pathAnnotationOnMethod = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(Path.class);
        if (pathAnnotationOnMethod != null) {
            uriBuilder = uriBuilder.path(resourceInfo.getResourceMethod());
        }
        return uriBuilder.toTemplate();
    }
}
```

This method does *not* work for nested resources like the following:

```java
@Path("api/users")
class UsersResource {

    @Inject
    UserResource userResource;

    @Inject
    UserAccessService userAccessService;

    @Context
    ResourceContext resourceContext;

    @Path("{id}")
    public UserResource user(@PathParam("id") long userId) {
        userAccessService.ensureAccessTo(userId);
        return resourceContext.initResource(userResource);
    }

}

@RequestScoped
class UserResource {

    @GET
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("id") long userId) {
      ...
    }
}
```

It throws an exception complaining that the `UserResource` has no `@Path`-annotation.

So my question is: how to resolve the URL pattern for nested (sub)resources?

Comment: One way to do it is to add a filter (with a very high priority) on every endpoint (which is invoked on both UsersResource.user and UserResource.getUser) and push the template URL onto some @RequestContext-scoped stack. When it is time to handle the response, I can access that stack and resolve the URL by hand. However, this sounds quite laborious and I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: Just a guess, but will [`UriInfo#getAbsolutePathBuilder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getAbsolutePathBuilder--) get you what you need?

Comment: I think, you need the remove the PathParam variable in `UserResource#getUser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```java
/**
 * Quarkus (or RESTEasy) doesn't make it easy to get the URI template including the
 * subresource. This custom class is used to track which subresource were invoked on
 * our way to the endpoint.
 */
@RequestScoped
public class SubresourcesTracked {

    private UriBuilder uriBuilder = null;

    public Optional<UriBuilder> getUriBuilder() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(uriBuilder);
    }

    public UriBuilder computeUriBuilderIfAbsent(Supplier<UriBuilder> supplier) {
        if (uriBuilder == null) {
            uriBuilder = supplier.get();
        }
        return uriBuilder;
    }
}
```

```java
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TrackingSubresource {
}
```

```java
/**
 * Quarkus (or RESTEasy) doesn't make it easy to get the URI template including the
 * subresource. This custom class is used to track which subresource were invoked on
 * our way to the endpoint.
 */
@Interceptor
@TrackingSubresource
public class TrackingSubresourceInterceptor {

    @Inject
    SubresourcesTracked subresourcesTracked;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object aroundInvoke(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        var method = context.getMethod();
        var uriBuilder = subresourcesTracked.computeUriBuilderIfAbsent(() -> {
            var resource = method.getDeclaringClass();
            Path pathAnnotationOnResource = resource.getAnnotation(Path.class);
            return UriBuilder.fromPath(pathAnnotationOnResource.value());
        });

        var pathAnnotationOnMethod = method.getAnnotation(Path.class);
        if (pathAnnotationOnMethod != null) {
            uriBuilder.path(pathAnnotationOnMethod.value());
        }

        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

In the request filter:

```java
    @Inject
    SubresourcesTracked subresourcesTracked;

    private String getUri() {
        var uriBuilder = subresourcesTracked.getUriBuilder().map(UriBuilder::toTemplate).map(UriBuilder::fromPath).orElseGet(() -> UriBuilder.fromResource(resourceInfo.getResourceClass()));
        var path = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(Path.class);
        if (path != null) {
            uriBuilder = uriBuilder.path(resourceInfo.getResourceMethod());
        }
        return uriBuilder.toTemplate();
    }
```